# Django Admin: list_filter and date_hierarchy with def function's variable

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

This is my models.py and admin.py file where I was supposed to do a filter with 'reportbranch' and date_hierarchy with 'reportdate'. but it is throwing following errors:

```
ERRORS:
 <class 'reports.admin.ReportSummaryAdmin'>: (admin.E116) The value of 'list_filter[1]' refers to 'reportbranch', which does not refer to a Field.
 <class 'reports.admin.ReportSummaryAdmin'>: (admin.E127) The value of 'date_hierarchy' refers to 'reportdate', which does not refer to a Field.
```

models.py

```
    class DailyReport(models.Model):
        report_type = models.CharField(max_length=500, choices=REPORT_TYPE, verbose_name="Type")
        date = models.DateField(verbose_name="Date")
        branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Branch")
        added_by = models.ForeignKey(User, editable=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
        added_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.date) + ' - ' +self.branch.name


    class ReportItem(models.Model):
        particular = models.ForeignKey(Particular, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Particular")
        Report = models.ForeignKey(DailyReport, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        total_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, verbose_name="Total Amount")
        quantity = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Quantity")
        remarks = models.CharField(max_length=5000, verbose_name="Remarks", null=True, blank=True)


    class ReportSummary(ReportItem):
        class Meta:
            proxy = True
            verbose_name = "Daily Report Summary"
            verbose_name_plural = "Daily Report Summaries"

        def reportdate(self):
            return self.Report.date

        def reportbranch(self):
            return self.Report.branch.name
```

admin.py

```
class ReportSummaryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ['reportbranch','reportdate','particular','Report','total_amount','quantity']
list_filter = ['particular','reportbranch']
date_hierarchy = 'reportdate'
```

Why it is throwing such issue, do I need to define anything with **init** function? I am confused over this issue's cause and its fix.

Answer (score 0):

Oops !! it was a simple fix that I was ignoring.

i got it fixed with this code

```
list_filter = ['Report__branch']
date_hierarchy = 'Report__date'
```